# Closing tag with comment produce "strange" behaviour

Tags: html, button, tags

Please someone can explain me why if i put the closing tag in a new line and i put a comment between one button and another the white space between the buttons isn’t  and the button is positioned side by side the other? Otherwise between a button and another a little white space is rendered, like the second and the third one. Can a comment change how an element is rendered by the browser?

Like this:

```
<div class="segmented-control__row">
      <button
        class="segmented-control__button segmented-control__button--active js-segmented-control__button"
        data-value="1"
      >
        Sort by price</button
      ><!--
            --><button
        class="segmented-control__button js-segmented-control__button"
        data-value="2"
      >
        Sort by name
      </button>
      <button
        class="segmented-control__button js-segmented-control__button"
        data-value="3"
      >
        Sort by relevance
      </button>
    </div>
```

the first one is with comment the second without. This is the result.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: The question appears to be "can someone explain why, when I comment out the whitespace, the whitespace disappears?" The answer seems self-evident.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand your example. Did you see a little white space between second and third button? Why doesn’t appear between the first and the second one? The only difference is a comment that couldn’t be rendered by the browser…so why  does this little white space is created?

Comment: A space doesn't appear between the first and second one because there is no space. There is a comment which, as you have just pointed out again, isn't rendered by the browser.

Comment: So why does this space appears between second and third one and the buttons don’t sit side by side? Also between second and third one must have any space, if white spaces are ignored by the browser.. sorry for my English I hope you will under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, whitespace isn't entirely ignored. A lot of whitespace (newlines, tabs, spaces) will be reduced to a single space, but that space can sometimes cause problems with your layout.

One option is to remove the whitespace entirely, and have the HTML on a single line.

Another option, the one you came across, is to use a comment. By placing the whitespace inside a comment, it won't be rendered and mess with your layout.

Info on whitespace in HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Comment: Thank you, I ve learned something new! At this link there is an example very similar to my issue.